# Correct way to write ColdFusion service to send json data and catch by angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, coldfusion

I'm Very stuck in this case when working all day :(. please help me.

I have website need using $http provider to call ColdFusion file from other domain.
let's say this is link to cfm file : `http://xample.com/getStockCodesTest.cfm`

---

this is may sample ColdFusion file:

```
<cfcontent
type="application/json"
/>
{
    "items": [
        {
            "StockCode" : { "col": "Stock Code", "value": "0231" },
            "Qty" : { "col": "Qty", "value": "DS" },
            "QtyOn" : { "col": "Qty On", "value": "Branch" },
            "QtyVal" : { "col": "Qty Val", "value": "200" },
            "ReleasedDate" : { "col": "Released Date", "value": "0" },
            "S" : { "col": "S", "value": "0" },
            "Description" : { "col": "Description", "value": "adfasdf" },
        }
    ]
}
```

---

this is angular code (i use coffeescript to write)

```
ajax = $http {
        url: 'http://xample.com/getStockCodesTest.cfm'
        method: 'JSONP'
        params: {
            callback: "JSON_CALLBACK"
        }
    }
    ajax.success (data, status, headers, config) ->
        console.log data
```

---

but when check firebug. it always return error:

[image]

so how can i have a correct way to write a test ColdFusion with content json like that and use angularjs to catch in to my web :(

Answer (score 4):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking.  But I can tell you that you are getting the error because you have invalid JSON.

[image]

That comma, right there, remove it. It makes for invalid JSON.

Answer (score 2):

You have to wrap your JSON with the input function name, when a JSONP call is made from AngularJS. That is the reason you see the error.

Example of JSONP response:

```
      /xxx.cfm?_jsonp=angular.callbacks._0 --- request

      //expected response is like this - a function from your coldfusion
      angular.callbacks._0([{"StockCode" : { "col":...
```

Then it will work.